# How to see disk usage graph on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance-monitoring

I experience a huge slow-down on server. And the more I inspect, the less I find out what's going on wrong there.

I think it might be related to I/O. On local PC, I can open Task Manager, and see the disk usage:

[image]

However, on server I can't find a (preferably easy) way to see how much is disk in usage and if it's become the bottleneck or not.

[image]

How do you see disk usage on Windows Server 2012?

Comment: Downvoter, this is an objective question and I really need this and I'm not a professional server administrator. So, please add a comment explaining why.

Comment: Downvotes are not required to be accompanied by a comment. Absent a comment, you can assume that a downvote is due to one of the reasons stated in the down arrow hover text.

Comment: Look into Windows Performance Counters.

Comment: Also, "I really need this" isn't a valid reason for asking a question.  I really need a pony, but I'm not about to ask for one on ServerFault.

Comment: Be polite to mark answer to your question, please!

Comment: @Luke some users don't (or don't want to) under rules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default Windows hide the entry because of a noted significant performance impact in collecting Disk metrics on a Server:

[image]

You need to [register the Disk Perfcounter](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/12/03/step-by-step-enabling-disk-performance-counters-in-windows-server-2012-r2-task-manager.aspx) before you see this entry.

1. close Taskmanager
2. open a `cmd.exe` as admin
3. run `diskperf -Y`
4. close cmd.exe and run Taskmgr

Now you see the entry:

[image]

To analyze disk activity deeper, install the [WPT](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx), run this xperf command and capture 1 minute of the activity:

> xperf -on
>   PROC_THREAD+LOADER+CSWITCH+DISPATCHER+DISK_IO+DISK_IO_INIT+FILENAME+FILE_IO+FILE_IO_INIT+PROFILE -stackwalk CSwitch+ReadyThread+FileCreate+FileCleanup+FileClose+FileRead+FileWrite+FileSetInformation+FileDelete+FileRename+DiskReadInit+DiskWriteInit+DiskFlushInit+Profile
>   -buffersize 2048 -MaxFile 2048 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\diagDISKFILEIO.etl

and analyze the trace file in WPA.exe for [DiskIO](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis) and [FileIO](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-45-WPT-File--Registry-Analysis).

Comment: You'll need to disable the Paging Executive before running this.

Comment: @joeqwerty for xperf and stackwalking yes. Win8 has it enabled by default. You need to do this in 7/2008R2

Comment: This is a very useful answer. Then how to understand which process is the culprit? For me, the `Disk` column chooser in `Processes` tab of Task Manager is grayed out.

Comment: click on "Open Resource Monitor" in the disk tab of Taskmgr. this opens a much better disk activity view here you can sort and filter for processes

Comment: is your question answered? Do you see the graph? if yes, "close" the question by marking the answer.

Comment: You need to open `cmd` as Administrator

Comment: @BYISHIMOAudace read it again. I've already written this in my answer ‍♂️

Comment: @magicandre1981  This doesn't answer the question, it doesn't show the disk space usage only the performance

Comment: @Vlax it answers it correctly, you simply don't understand the question and answer.

Answer (score 2):

Or just open Resource Monitor (a Windows built-in program). Click Start, and search for "Resource Monitor" which should give you what you are looking for.

[image: Resource Monitor]